# cut first character of Php request server url

Tags: php

How can I cut off the '/' at the beginning of the word?

example: mysite/article

Using this php:

```
$request_url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $request_url;
```

This result is: /article

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain well: I use this: $request_url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $request_url; to get the last part of the link: website.com/item and it prints into the content as: /item I need to cut the: / when is printed. sorry, I don't not much about php so i really appreciate if you can the answer complete and simple. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the first character from a string using ltrim

$str = ltrim($request_url, '/');

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string into an array.

Then remove first element from array using [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Again [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array to string.

```
<?php
$str = 'mysite/article/testing/working/example/now';
$tmp = explode('/', $str);
array_shift($tmp);
echo ! empty($tmp) ? implode('/', $tmp) : '';
// OUTPUTS: article/testing/working/example/now
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
$example = "mysite/artic4le"; 
$val = explode("/",$example);
print_r($val[0]); 
print_r($val[1]); 
?>
```